# PHP APC installed but not enabled

Tags: apc

on an amazon linux ami I've succesfully (I think) installed apc (with yum or pecl. tried both) but I'm not able to enable it (sorry for the pun).

php -i says:

```
apc

APC Support => disabled
Version => 3.1.15-dev
APC Debugging => Disabled
MMAP Support => Enabled
MMAP File Mask =>
Locking type => pthread mutex Locks
Serialization Support => broken
Revision => $Revision: 329725 $
Build Date => May 28 2013 18:03:40

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
apc.cache_by_default => On => On
```

(and so on...)

extension=apc.so and apc.enabled=1 are in /etc/php.d/apc.ini (and php -i confirm that /etc/php.d/apc.ini is parsed). 
I tried also to put them in /etc/php.ini to no avail. (And of course I dutifully restarted httpd every time). 
Now I really don't know what to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apc is showing disabled , but did you check whether its working or not , as most of the time it shows disabled but works fine.

I installed the same in my centOS and checked that about the issue , me also getting the same output of php -i and but everything is working fine please see the below screen shot.

[image]

Comment: apc.php says:No cache info available.  APC does not appear to be running.

Comment: do you know any other method to check if it's working?

Comment: I updated my answer about how to check , let me know if still unclear

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH PRASHANT! It is working indeed. What is still bewildering me is that running php apc.php from the command line gives "No cache info available"... Anyhow: it works. Thank you so much.

Comment: didn't I? Sorry, I'm new here. Doesn't putting the green flag means accept the answer?